# gcloud: add docker run arguments while deploy docker container to GCE

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I need to add `--shm-size` command to `docker run` while I deploy container image from `Container Registry`.

According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#overriding_the_default_command_to_execute_on_container_startup) I need to use `Arguments` fields under `Advanced container options` but it doesn't work for me.
I've added `--shm-size 1G` line like that:

[image]

`docker exec -it 68d... df -h` still returns default shm size:
`shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm`

Could somebody suggest how can I solve my issue?
I also have tried to increase it manually inside docker container but faced
`mount: /dev/shm: permission denied.` issue.

**UPDATE**
**Solution:**
I've created a bash script as an entry point which is set up  /dev/shm size manually:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "none /dev/shm tmpfs defaults,size=500m 0 0" >> /etc/fstab 
mount -o remount /dev/shm

dotnet Worker.dll
```

Dockerfile:

```
....
USER root
COPY ["Worker/start.sh", "app/"]
CMD ["/bin/bash", "app/start.sh"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments under the advance container option is just like passing arg to ENTRYPOINT.
Query compute metadata "gce-container-declaration" using command from the container vm 'curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/gce-container-declaration"'

For your use case, create non-container VM, then install the docker yourself and run a container using our docker shm arg